# How to increment only digits of string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I may have following type strings

A1 or 1A or AB....1 or 1AB......

so how to increment only digits of above type of strings in javascript?

```
var adminNo = data.Admission_No.slice(-2);
                alert(adminNo);
                var removedNo = data.Admission_No.substring(data.Admission_No.length-1);
                alert(removedNo);
```

Comment: What is the expected result for `A001`? For `A999`?

Comment: for A001 = A002 and for A999=A1000

Comment: @georg have u answer above comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the replace method as shown in demo below

```js
    function incrementer(input)
    {
       return input.replace(/\d+/, function(match){ return parseInt(match) + 1 });
    }

    alert(incrementer("A1"));
    alert(incrementer("1A"));
```

This will find the integer anywhere in the input string and increment it by one.

Answer (score 3):

```
string.replace(/\d+/, function(n){ return ++n });
```

Comment: with A01 not working...mean getting only A2 ..not getting A02

Comment: Becase 01 + 1 = 2 not 02... it's standard. Would be more advanced function to support zerofill...

Comment: for 07k71a0507 incrementing 8k71a0507 where I need to increment like 07k71a0508

Comment: @ArmaanAhmed use this to replace all numbers: `string.replace(/\d+/g, function(n){ return ++n });` (added `g` to regexp params)

Comment: I not need to increment first digit in like this strings. just increment only last  digits.

Comment: please update if have any solution for if string has two side digits then increment only last part digit.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by taking out integer from your string
Its big long, but more self-explainatory

```
var youroriginalstring="A1"
var withNoDigits = youroriginalstring.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');
var yournumber = youroriginalstring.replace ( /[^\d.]/g, '' );
var incNos=yournumber +1;
var newString = incnos + "withNoDigits"
```